# 'Gemfile not found' after typing rails -v

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Noob here.

I recently installed rails following the instructions laid out here >> http://installrails.com/steps/install_rails

When I input rails -v in my root directory I get the rails version as expected:

> I am typing...rails -v
> Rails 5.0.1

However, when I cd into my documents folder I am getting 'Gemfile not found' :

> I am typing...cd documents
>
> I am typing...rails -v
>
> **/Users/Matt/Documents/Gemfile not found**

I tried to install rails inside the documents directory, but still received the same output:

> I am typing...gem install rails
>
> Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
>
> Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.1
>
> Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
>
> 1 gem installed
>
> I am typing...rails -v
>
> **/Users/Matt/Documents/Gemfile not found**

I can't create any rails applications with rails new while inside my documents folder either. Here is my ruby load_path:

> I am typing...irb
>
> 2.4.0 :001 > $LOAD_PATH
>
> => ["/Users/Matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-
> darwin15", "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0",
> "/Users/Matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15"]

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

RVM can solve your problem, you can have several versions of ruby installed, what you should do is create a gemset per project.

To install it go to: https://rvm.io/rvm/install, use Install RVM stable with ruby.

After installing it, go to the directory where you want to create the new rails project and make the following commands:

rvm gemset create yourApp
rvm gemset use yourAppName
gem install rails
rails new yourAppName

And you must do that for every project you want to create, this will help you to keep the appropriate version of ruby, rails, etc. For each project.

Comment: I tried running the rvm gemset commands, but still get Gemfile not found.                                                 I am typing...rvm gemset use yourApp
Using ruby-2.4.0 with gemset yourApp
I am typing...gem install rails
Fetching: rails-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.1
Installing ri documentation for rails-5.0.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
I am typing...rails new yourApp
/Users/Matt/Documents/Gemfile not found

Comment: Is there a way to manually add the necessary Gemfile into my Documents directory since the installers aren't working properly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a broken installation of ruby/rails.

Use RVM(Ruby Version Manager) to manage your ruby versions/installations. It is still good to use even if you are only using one version. Once RVM is installed, you can the install rails gem. It keeps everything clean so that you don't have to deal with paths etc.

Try the following to get your environment in 'rails' shape:

## Install RVM

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

## Install Ruby(change the version to whatever you wish)

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

## Set the default ruby version

```
rvm default use 2.3.1
```

## Go to a directory where you keep your projects

```
cd /path/to/my/projects
```

## Install rails gem

```
gem install rails
```

## Check rails version

```
rails -v
```

## Create a new Project as a test

```
rails new test-project
```

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: You can also try sourcing your ~/.bash_profile (`source ~/.bash_profile`) as well to ensure that updated paths etc. are loaded in the terminal you are working in

Comment: I tried reinstalling RVM and rails within my project directory but still get 'Gemfile not found'. I do notice that when I install rails only 1 gem is installed, which I believe is unusual. Could you elaborate on sourcing my bash_profile?

Comment: It appears as if the problem is isolated within my Documents directory, as I've tried cding into other folders from my Root directory and rails appears to work. I know at one point, I was fiddling around in my Documents and deleted a hidden Gemfile and Gemlock file trying to address a different issue.

Comment: Gemfiles are specific to the a project. I would recommend creating a subfolder under Documents for your rails app, then run `rails new ...` from that directory(since you are no having issues in other directories). "Gemfile not found" usually occurs after running `bundle install`, and there is no Gemfile present.

Comment: I'm having issues with all directories under Documents (including the Documents root). If I create a new subfolder within Documents it also experiences the same Gemfile problem. Rails is only working for directories outside the Documents tree.

Comment: I just did a test and I can create rails apps in the Documents directory, or and subdirectory. It sounds like there are some issues specific to your local dev environment. Did you make any changes to the Documents directory at the OS level? If so, maybe this is causing a conflict.

Perhaps just use a directory outside Documents so that you can move forward? It is difficult to troubleshoot this issue without actually seeing things happening real time.